# Could not process app this time due to general error....everytime shows this error while validating my app.Why?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am publishing my app to appstore but while validating it always shows could not process at this time due to genaral error....its driving me crazy as i am getting same error for last three days..Plzz provide a fine solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be an iTC issue, other users have been reporting difficulties lately.

Comment: Are you using iOS 8? Apple does not allow submissions for future software releases until they say so (closer to release).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohh i found the solution for this it was happening becoz my apple account expires..i renewed my account and it works...just created new certificates and thats all !!
If anything like that appears then you first check your apple developer account. Generally its becoz of some problem with the developer account or certificates.
You just delete old certificates and create new one then it should be fine.